# visual sourcesafe online server

Tags: vss

I would like to upload my code to a visual sourcesafe server, but I want to avoid paying $500 to run my own server.  Is there a $5 / month server that allows you to upload Visual Studio code online somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SourceAnywhere bills](http://www.dynamsoft.com/Products/SourceAnywhere-Hosting-Version-Control-Source-Control.aspx) them selves as the "The Hosted Microsoft Visual SourceSafe (VSS) Alternative", but it looks to be more than $5/mo.  I've never used them so no comment there.  It was listed in [this list](http://weblogs.asp.net/fmarguerie/archive/2005/04/27/404793.aspx) of hosted source control providers.

Is there a reason you are stuck on VSS? There are plenty of alternative source control systems, for example [SubVersion](http://subversion.tigris.org/) is open source and so completely free (and [will run on Windows](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001093.html))

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure of anywhere that will do this for that sort of price - Visual Source Safe is not really designed for a hosted environment and I have never seen anywhere that offers it.

Your best bet will be to get the cheapest Windows VPS you can find and install it yourself, alternatively, take a look at a different source control application such as Git Hub, where you can get private[source code hosting](http://github.com/plans) from $7 a month. (cannot really recommend this over any others, just giving an example)

Comment: +1 for GitHub. If he can move away from VSS it's a very good option.